# Generically typed HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, generics, hashset

I've found some information on this topic out there, but it's all been about typical classes—I have no idea how to convert the class below to a generic version.

I have inherited existing code that uses a SqlHashSet class to set integer values for parameters to the database.  It looks like this:

```
namespace Services
{
    public class SqlHashSet : HashSet<int>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
    {
        SqlDataRecord ret = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("value", SqlDbType.Int));       
        foreach (var data in this)
        {
            ret.SetValue(0, data);
            yield return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

I must use SqlHashSet because of the structure of the code.  My problem is that I need a SqlHashSet of **strings**.

I'm thinking maybe I can use `HashSet<T>` in the class declaration but then I also have to check if the value is of type SqlDbType.int or SqlDbType.VarChar

So, my questions are:

1. Can I do this?
2. What do I need to do to use `<T>`?
3. Maybe there isn't a third question; maybe then I can step through the code once I have it working with a generic type and figure out how to determine the SqlDbType to set the value to.

Comment: `Can I do this?` <= no, the code you have shown here will not compile so no. A `foreach` loop that `yield`s a result has to be a part of a method body, it cant exist on its own in the class body.

Comment: `What do I need to do to use <T>?` <= maybe a better question is would the change be worth it? There are a limited number of primitive sql types AND the SqlType does not have to allign with exactly 1 .net primitive type, usually the relationship depends on your model structure. Example: .net DateTime could map to Date, DateTime, or DateTime2. This might not be the best place to use a generic.

Comment: You could take the easy way out and have two generic parameters, one for the `HashSet` and one for the `SqlDbType`. Your class would look something like `SqlHashSet<TManaged, TSql>`. Alternatively, rewrite the code to not use this `SqlHashSet` and stick to the library types.

Comment: How is `T` used in this class? Is it only required by the `HashSet<T>` base class?

Comment: @AndrewPiliser - you cant use the value of `SqlDbType` as a generic parameter.

Comment: @Igor That is true, instead it would have to be passed in as a normal parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @Igor - The actual code is on a locked down server (no copy/paste), so I may have accidentally included a typo but the actual code does compile.  Sorry!

Comment: @AndrewPiliser - We will be rewriting the code in phase 2.  Right now, I'm trying to work with someone else's mucked up code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a base class:

```
public abstract class SqlHashSetBase<T> : HashSet<T>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    protected abstract SqlDbType DbType { get; }

    IEnumerator<SqlDataRecord> IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        SqlDataRecord ret = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("value", this.DbType));
        foreach (T data in this)
        {
            ret.SetValue(0, data);
            yield return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

then change your existing class:

```
public class SqlHashSet : SqlHashSetBase<int> {
    protected override SqlDbType DbType {
        get { return SqlDbType.Int; }
    }
}
```

and add a new one:

```
public class SqlStringHashSet : SqlHashSetBase<string> {
    protected override SqlDbType DbType {
        get { return SqlDbType.NVarChar; }
    }
}
```

You might want to consider extracting the `T => SqlDbType` mapping into its own class and passing it as a parameter instead of using the abstract method. You might also want to consider using composition instead of inheriting directly from `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: Once I got tangled in the SqlDbType and DbType I ended up using your answer.  I still don't have it working quite right.  Being completely new to SQL server code, this crap is hard!

Comment: Hey, Lee:  I have to get this working or scrap it and go with ids.  I know somewhere in the history of the universe that somebody has got to have tried to send a table of strings to the sql server db.    I feel like this is very close.  In fact too close to turn back now.  I copied your code (word for word) but execution gets stuck in an infinite loop in SqlHashSetBase.  A little help, if you can.

Comment: @Patricia - I think you'll have to implement `IEnumerable<SqlDatatRecord>` explicitly to stop it hiding `GetEnumerator()` from `HashSet<T>`. Then you can iterate over the items in the set instead of recursively calling `GetEnumerator`. See update.

Comment: OK - I get to the new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("value", this.DbType)) statement and I get the error "The dbType NVarChar is invalid for this constructor.

Comment: @Patricia - It looks like you have to use a different constructor of `SqlMetaData` for `string` where you pass the maximum length. Do all your string columns use the same max length? Otherwise you could add a lookup from column name => length if you know the columns in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(Note that the code you have posted doesn't compile; you can't write statements directly in a class, they have to be in a method)

You can't create a truly generic class, because you need to use a different `SqlDbType` depending on the type of `T`. But if you don't mind doing something slightly ugly, you can do this:

```
public class SqlHashSet<T> : HashSet<T>, IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>
{
    private static readonly SqlDbType _sqlDbType = GetSqlDbType();
    private static SqlDbType GetSqlDbType()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
            return SqlDbType.Int;
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return SqlDbType.String;

        ...

        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't find the SqlDbType for {typeof(T)}");
    }

    ...

    SqlDataRecord ret = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("value", _sqlDbType));
}
```

The approach suggested in Lee's answer is similar but a little cleaner, if you don't mind the drawback of having to create a separate class for each value type.

Comment: Hey, once I got tangled in the SqlDbType and DbType I ended up using Lee's answer.  I still don't have it working quite right but I'm going to have to give him the points.  Thank you for your help.